# Recursive type definition in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Suppose I have this code in Haskell and I want to try to come up with something like it in Scala:

```
data CatList q a = E | C a (q (CatList q a))

instance Queue q => CatenableList (CatList q) where
   -- methods
```

Note that `CatList` is either empty, or is an element plus a queue (as defined by a typeclass `q`) of `CatList`s. In Scala, I'm trying to do something like

```
sealed trait CatList[+Q, +E]

object Empty extends CatList[Nothing, Nothing]

case class C[Q[_], E](x: E, q: Q[CatList[Q, E]]) extends CatList[Q[???], E]
```

but the problem is, `Q[_]` takes parameters, so I need to provide something in the `extends` clause, which leads to `CatList[Q[CatList[Q[???], E], E]` which is confusing.

I can try a Haskell approach, saying that `Q[_]` is nothing but a type, and go with

```
sealed trait CatList[+Q[_], +E]

object Empty extends CatList[Nothing, Nothing]

case class C[Q[_], E](x: E, q: Q[_]) extends CatList[Q[_], E]
```

but that fails with

```
Error:(16, 56) Q[_] takes no type parameters, expected: one
  case class C[Q[_], E](x: E, q: Q[_]) extends CatList[Q[_], E]
                                                       ^
```

So the question is, is there a way to get around that?

Comment: You've changed the question completely. Please restore the original question and ask this one separately. (Also, `q` is not a typeclass in that Haskell code, it's just a type variable of kind `* -> *`)

Comment: Yep, apologies, as often happens I tried to clarify the question a bit, and realised that while I do have the recursion problem, the main problem is completely different, and... Anyway, reverted, will accept in a second.

Comment: Asked a separate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947116/use-type-parameters-type-argument-as-field-type-in-scala?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
sealed trait CatList[+Q[_], +E]

object Empty extends CatList[Nothing, Nothing]

case class C[+Q[_], +E](x: E, q: Q[CatList[Q, E]]) extends CatList[Q, E]
```

`[_]` has different meanings in type parameter declaration like `trait CatList[+Q[_], +E]` ("`Q` is a type constructor") and in use like `extends CatList[Q[_], E]` ("`Q` with some unknown parameter").