# Use type parameter's type argument as field type in Scala

Tags: scala, types

So following up on [Recursive type definition in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934003/recursive-type-definition-in-scala), I now have my type for the data-bearing structure of `CatenableListFromQueue`:

```
object CatenableListFromQueue {

  sealed trait CatList[+Q, +E]

  object Empty extends CatList[Nothing, Nothing]

  case class C[Q[_], E](x: E, q: Q[CatList[Q, E]]) extends CatList[Q, E]
}
```

now the intended value for the parameter Q is, naturally, a queue. My `Queue` itself is a type class, i.e. it only defines the methods for some generic data-bearing structure:

```
trait Queue[E, Q] {

  def empty: Q

  def isEmpty: Q => Boolean

  def snoc: (Q, E) => Q

  def head: Q => E

  def tail: Q => Q
}
```

It seems to work just fine for me, e.g.

```
class BatchedQueue[E] extends Queue[E, (List[E], List[E])] {
  override def empty: (List[E], List[E]) = (Nil, Nil)

  override def isEmpty: ((List[E], List[E])) => Boolean = {
    case (Nil, _) => true
    case _ => false
  }

  val checkf: (List[E], List[E]) => (List[E], List[E]) = {
    case (Nil, r) => (r.reverse, Nil)
    case q => q
  }

  override def snoc: ((List[E], List[E]), E) => (List[E], List[E]) = {
    case ((f, r), x) => checkf(f, x :: r)
  }

  override def tail: ((List[E], List[E])) => (List[E], List[E]) = {
    case (Nil, _) => throw new IllegalStateException("tail called on an empty queue")
    case ((_ :: f), r) => checkf(f, r)
  }

  override def head: ((List[E], List[E])) => E = {
    case (Nil, _) => throw new IllegalStateException("head called on an empty queue")
    case ((x :: _), _) => x
  }
}
```

That all was going well until I needed to create a `CatenableListFromQueue`, which holds a data structure from the previous question with the data-bearing structure of the `Queue`, `Queue#Q`:

```
class CatenableListFromQueue[E, CL, Q](queue: Queue[E, Q]) extends CatenableList[E] {

  type CL = CatList[queue#Q, E]
```

So in my ideal world the class gets an instance of `Queue`, i.e. the implementation of the queue operations over some structure (here: `Queue#Q`), and in turn creates and handles a `CatList` of the actual elements and the `Queue#Q`s containing further `CatList`s.

The problem is, I cannot seem to come up with a way to code that in Scala; in Haskell, it seems as trivial as:

```
data CatList q a = E | C a (q (CatList q a))

instance Queue q => CatenableList (CatList q) where
   -- methods
```

But in Scala I cannot come up with any way to encode the same as my `Queue` requires that data-bearing structure as a parameter, and the data-bearing naturally contains it elements which in this case contain further data-bearing structures of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, following Haskell's approach was the right way:

```
object CatenableListFromQueue {

  sealed trait CatList[+Q[_], +E]

  object Empty extends CatList[Nothing, Nothing]

  case class C[Q[_], E](x: E, q: Q[Susp[CatList[Q, E]]]) extends CatList[Q, E]
}

trait CatenableListFromQueue[E, QBS[_]] extends CatenableList[E, CatList[QBS, E]] {

  type Q = Queue[Susp[CatList[QBS, E]], QBS[Susp[CatList[QBS, E]]]]

  def q: Q

  type CL = CatList[QBS, E]

  def just(e: E): CL = C(e, q.empty)

  // etc.
```

So we keep the `CatenableListFromQueue` a trait, and use it later with a specific type for `QBS`:

```
new CatenableListFromQueue[Int, HoodMelvilleQueue.Repr] {
  val q = new HoodMelvilleQueue[Susp[CL]]
}
```

This way, it all compiles just fine, and seems to work well.